# ASP File Is Working, but

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have the script working, but I don't know enough about the server side. What has to be running on the server (Microsoft Server, Enterpise Edition) to process a client PHP upload?

http://pwhittle.dlinkddns.com/bin/

Comment: Patrick, generally speaking you should provide details on what you've tried.  You say the script is working, but no one really knows what that means.  Also, some details on exactly what part of the problem you are having trouble with will help.

Comment: Also, you mention three different technologies here: asp, .net, and php.  And the webpage you reference appears to have been built with Word or something like it and posts back to a php page...

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what he wants to do, I've seen this before.

He wants to show the progress of a file he uploads.
It works via JavaScript and iFrame, but when I tried, I wasn't able to get ASP.NET to do the same as PHP, probably because ASP.NET is doing it synchronously by default, while PHP is async.

If that's indeed what you want, I reccommend JQuery uploadify.

You find more info on JQuery Uploadify with WebForms in my post here:
[Multiple fileuploads with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797988/multiple-fileuploads-with-asp-net-mvc/4798165#4798165)